# Is there a difference between for case let and a for loop + if let?

Tags: swift

I just learned about for case let, and these two versions of a loop have the same output. It made me wonder, is there any difference (in performance or otherwise) in for case let and a normal for loop with a if-then statement?

I started considering this because I hear that I shouldn't treat switch case and if-then's the same, the can accomplish very different things.

```
class Daddy {

}

class Son: Daddy {
    func speak() {
        print("I am son!")
    }
}

var people = [Son(), Daddy()]

for case let person as Son in people {
    person.speak()
}

for person in people {
    if let son = person as? Son {
        son.speak()
    }
}
```

Comment: As with many performance-related questions, the answer is typically the same: (a) it wouldn't matter unless you're talking about thousands or hundreds of thousands of elements; so under normal condition, optimize for code clarity, and (b) if you do have a performance critical situation, then measure each case with all the compiler optimizations turned on

Comment: I'd say the question as it stands is opinion-based. My opinion is that `for case let` is a much less known idiom. So it's cooler though somewhat more obscure than the `for ... if let`, but in fact the vast majority of Swift programmers would probably write the latter.

Comment: As for performance, well hey, the `for case let` has to cycle thru the whole sequence just like `for ... in`, so what are the odds?

Comment: Use whichever syntax you find most clear and expressive, and don't worry about performance except in the most extreme of cases. Once you start using `for case let ... { ... }` syntax (or `for ... where ... { ... }` syntax, for that matter), I suspect that you will likely find the nested `for ... { if ... { ... } }` syntax to be cumbersome, but as clear here, it's a matter of opinion, and thus off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The `for case let ...` (and the `for ... where ...`) syntax does have a minor and subtle advantage, insofar as it can sometimes make it easier to reason about one’s code at a glance. If you see `for ... { if { ... } }`, you have to scan further in your code to make sure there isn't a lingering `else` clause that you have to reason about. That is not necessary in the `for case let` syntax. Clearly in your trivial example that's not an issue, but if it was more complicated, it is something to consider. (It's similar to the reason why early exit code, with `guard let`, is easier to reason about.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other people have commented, performance of the code isn't the concern. Instead, creating a mental framework for decision-making is the concern.

i.e. How can you, as the programmer, reduce the time it takes for your brain to channel a decision out into the code? You cannot allow yourself freedom to make different decisions every time, or your own performance will suffer.

Any choice you make could be acceptable, but not having a framework for decision-making is not.

---

A mnemonic I recommend is the thought pattern, "I am going to take advantage of language features that encapsulate boilerplate, instead of allowing myself to put that boilerplate into the source". That will leave you with:

```swift
for case let son as Son in people {
  son.speak()
}
```

`for case let` syntax is a way to filter a sequence based on optionals.

Given this:

```swift
var daddies: [Daddy?] = [Son(), Daddy()]
```

Here, daddy is of type `Daddy?`:

```
for daddy in daddies {
```

…but here, it's unwrapped to `Daddy`:

```
for case let daddy? in daddies {
```

And this…

```swift
for person in people {
  if let son = person as? Son {
    son.speak()
  }
}
```

…is just syntactic sugar for this:

```swift
for person in people {
  if case let son? = person as? Son {
    son.speak()
  }
}
```

The intermediate step that would demonstrate lifting the if statement to the for loop (which is the correct scope for it) will not compile…

```swift
for case let son? as? Son in people {
```

…so instead, you have to jump right to

```swift
for case let son as Son in people {
```

which is the same syntactic sugar used by switch statements, which also disallow conditional casting.